# Plotting combination bar and line chart with dual y axis using flot

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I planned on using the jquery charting library flot; before embarking on this adventure I wanted to check that combination line and bar charts are supported by flot.

Are they ?

If they are not, can anyone recommend a suitable javascript library for supporting such graphs.

An example fo what I mean is here [Combi chart with dual axis](http://www.swiftchart.com/example_3.htm#barlinemix_ex1)

Also is flot ok with ie6, I have scanned the documentation and done some preliminary testing and found no problems.  Wanted to double check I would not come across any showstoppers ... ?

Edit: I see it does support combi bar and line charts with dual axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combination bar and line graphs are indeed supported - http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html. Flot works on IE by including excanvas which emulates the HTML5 canvas - http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/.

Hope this helps.